# Cast object to another by matched property at values

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typescript-typings

I need to convert one object to another according some rules.

- There is `Types` enum;
- There are two interfaces `Color` and `Number`;
- There is `ValuesByType` interface where `Types` enum mapped to interfaces `Color` and `Number`;
- Three is `source` object (dictionary/Record) with `type` property that is `Types` enum.

I need to write types for `convert` function that returns a new object with the same keys as `source` object but values should refs to interfaces that are mapped at `ValuesByType`.

Example:

```
interface Color {}
interface Number {}

enum Types {
  Color,
  Number,
}

interface ValuesByType {
  [Types.Color]: Color,
  [Types.Number]: Number,
}

interface SourceValue<T extends Types = Types> {
  type: T;
}


// Need to define types for this function
function convert(source: SourceValue) {
  ...
}

const source: SourceValue = {
  foo: {
    type: Types.Color,
  },
  bar: {
    type: Types.Number,
  },
};

const result = convert(source);

// The type of "result" veriable should be:
// {
//     foo: Color,
//     bar: Number
// }
```

I tried this way but it does not work:

```
export type Convert = <
  T extends Types,
  S extends Record<keyof S, SourceValue<T>>
>(
  source: S,
) => Record<keyof S, ValuesByType[T]>;
```

---

- [Here is playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Color%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20opacity%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20enum%20Types%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20Number%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ValuesByType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTypes.Color%5D%3A%20Color%3B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTypes.Number%5D%3A%20Number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SourceValue%3CT%20extends%20Types%20%3D%20Types%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Convert%20%3D%20%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20Types%2C%0D%0A%20%20S%20extends%20Record%3Ckeyof%20S%2C%20SourceValue%3CT%3E%3E%0D%0A%3E(%0D%0A%20%20source%3A%20S%2C%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20Record%3Ckeyof%20S%2C%20ValuesByType%5BT%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Need%20to%20define%20types%20for%20this%20function%0D%0Aconst%20convert%3A%20Convert%20%3D%20source%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20Object.keys(source).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(memo%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(source%5Bkey%5D.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Types.Color%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20memo%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20opacity%3A%201%2C%20%2F%2F%20just%20example%20valuee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20'%23fff'%2C%20%2F%2F%20just%20example%20valuee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Types.Number%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20memo%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%201%2C%20%2F%2F%20just%20example%20valuee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20_source%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.Number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20convert(_source)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Color%20%7C%20Number%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20shoulde%20be%20Number%0D%0Aresult.bar%0D%0A) with this issue
- [Here is playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Color%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20opacity%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Number%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Types%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20Number%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ValuesByType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTypes.Number%5D%3A%20Number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5BTypes.Color%5D%3A%20Color%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Key%3CT%20extends%20Types%20%3D%20Types%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20key%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20GetValue%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Types%3E(key%3A%20Key%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20ValuesByType%5BT%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20source%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.Number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20get%3A%20GetValue%20%3D%20(props)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20source%5Bprops.key%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20result%20type%20is%20Color%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20get(%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20Types.Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20key%3A%20'foo'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A) with very similar example for getter function by type and type mapper interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue you'll want to clear up when solving this issue is the type of your input `_sources` object. On your TS Playground link, it's currently typed as:

```
const _source: { 
  foo: { type: Types; }; 
  bar: { type: Types; };
};
```

Notice how the `type` parameters are getting set to just `Types` instead of a concrete `Types.Color` or `Types.Number`.

On Typescript 3.4 you can fix this by adding `as const` after the definition:

```
const _source = {
  foo: { type: Types.Color },
  bar: { type: Types.Number },
} as const;
```

or, prior to 3.4, you can use `Types.Color as Types.Color` to get typescript to treat these as literal values.

After that is cleared up, a Mapped Type will get your the return value you need. I wrote this as a generic helper type.

```
type ConvertedSources<T extends Record<string, SourceValue<any>>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: ValuesByType[T[key]['type']]
};
```

If you pass in `typeof _source` to this, you'll see how each property in `_source` will get mapped to the corresponding value type based on your `ValuesByType` interface.

Then, you just need to make your function use this in its signature, preserving the same type constraint:

```
function convert<
  TSources extends Record<string, SourceValue<any>>
  >(source: TSources): ConvertedSources<TSources> { ... }
```

Note that you'll also need to cast the result of your `reduce()` call to `ConvertedSources<TSources>`, or change some of the inner code to preserve the types.

[TS Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Color%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20opacity%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20enum%20Types%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20Number%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ValuesByType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTypes.Color%5D%3A%20Color%3B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTypes.Number%5D%3A%20Number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SourceValue%3CT%20extends%20Types%20%3D%20Types%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ConvertedSources%3CT%20extends%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20SourceValue%3Cany%3E%3E%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20ValuesByType%5BT%5Bkey%5D%5B'type'%5D%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20convert%3C%0D%0A%20%20TSources%20extends%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20SourceValue%3Cany%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3E(source%3A%20TSources)%3A%20ConvertedSources%3CTSources%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20Object.keys(source).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(memo%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(source%5Bkey%5D.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Types.Color%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20memo%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20opacity%3A%201%2C%20%2F%2F%20just%20example%20valuee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20'%23fff'%2C%20%2F%2F%20just%20example%20valuee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Types.Number%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20memo%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%201%2C%20%2F%2F%20just%20example%20valuee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%20as%20ConvertedSources%3CTSources%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20_source%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.Color%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.Number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%20as%20const%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Just%20to%20demonstrate%3B%20this%20line%20does%20nothing.%0D%0Atype%20ExpectedResultType%20%3D%20ConvertedSources%3Ctypeof%20_source%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20convert(_source)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Now%20it's%20Number%0D%0Aresult.bar%0D%0A)

Comment: `ValuesByType[T[key]['type']]` this solved my problem. I tried this way but with wrong syntax  `ValuesByType[T[key].type]`. Thanks a lot